# Import excel files in SQlite with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHtZ8.jpg)I am trying to import to SQlite database using python script and pandas, several excel files, with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.xls'):
        df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        df.columns = ['Data',
                      'Hour',
                      'Series 1',
                      'Series 2',
                      'Series 3',
                      'Series 4']
        conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        df.to_sql('table1', conn, if_exists='replace')
        print(df)
```

But, every time it either replaces the values or creates duplicates every time i run the script, any idea how to preserve uniqe values in SQLite?

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11nG6.jpg)
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpxzj.jpg)

Comment: You are currently telling python to load the dataframe into "table1" and if it exists, then it should replace "table1" with the current file.
Do you want to append to the table, or create a new one for each excel file?

Comment: I need to append, but even changing to if_exists='append', it does not help since the values are writen in the database table1, every time I run the code in python. I think I need same uniqness key?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of your data? How it looks, how you want it to look and how it ends up looking when using this method.

Comment: I have updated the question with a view of input. I have several excels like this, which are imported through the script. But the issue I am runing now is that every time I run the script it is importing them, thus creating duplicates.

Comment: Can you show me what the output with duplicates looks like?

Comment: I have updated a link with output, as you can see i have inputet only 2 files with 24 values

Comment: So let me see if I understand correctly:
You want to have 4 columns with 24 rows. You want to update these every day, however, you only want to reupload the values that are changing cell-by-cell. So, if hour 2 goes from 17-17-1-11 to 15-15-1-11, you only want series 1 and 2 to change to 15 and 15 and the rest of the data frame to stay as it was?

Comment: I will upload new date everyday, but is some cases I may need to reupload the same date. Lets say I have uploaded date 1st to 3rd of September. Then I will upload day 4th of September. each time the structure will be the same, so 4 time series with 24 values. I want the values to be stored for each day in the database. At a later stage I will query them from SQLite database to excel(csv). For the moment I am working only on the import process, this database will grow each day with 4 time series each 24 values.

Comment: I have posted what I think is a solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this either by adding a column with the date, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()

df["Date"] = today
# Make sure you have if_exists="append"
```

Or you can make a separate in the same db and dynamically name them the date, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()

df.to_sql('{}'.format(str(today)), conn)
```

Reloading days should be fine using if_exists="replace"